# v.clean what input feature type for polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, topology

I have a polygon layer where the Topology Checker detects hundreds of overlaps and tiny gaps. So I want to use the v.clean tool to clean the topology. For cleaning, I selected the tools bpol, rmarea and rmdupl as recommended in [How to Clean Topology Error in QGIS](https://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html)
.

But what I have to select as input feature type? There's no option for polygon.

Comment: I typically use the line, boundary and area for my input features, and break, snap, bpol and rmarea for my tools, for a general clean.

Answer (score 0):

`v.clean` should decide automatically based on the input type, but if you want to specify the input option, you should use `area` for polygon vectors.

[image]